# Virtual vs Interface poco, what's faster?

Tags: interface, virtual, poco, inlining

I am maintaining an application which has been designed like this:

```
messy code --abuses--> simplePoco (POCO data capsule)
```

The data capsule is a simple class with lots of getters and setters (properties) It uses a DI framework and consistently use the IoC container to provide instances of the data capsule (lucky me!).

The problem is, I need to introduce a "change notification" mechanism into `simplePoco`

```
messy code --abuses--> simplePoco 
               |
               V
         changes logger,
         status monitor
     (I wanna know about changes)
```

I have a few options:

- Introduce an `IPoco` and modify the messy code, so that I can have `simplePoco` for the speed or `notifyingPoco` when I want change notification (selectively slow)? or ...
- Make everything virtual and roll my own custom `notifyingPoco` class on top of `simplePoco` (even slower)?
- design patterns that I do not know?

It is a client/server system but I'm just modifying the server part so if possible, I'd rather  *not* touch the messy code or the client code (there are serializers and reflections and scary ninja stuffs...) as to not accidentally break anything.

Would using an interface prevents JIT from inlining the calls to getter/setter?

What's the best way to go considering that simplePoco instances are *heavily* abused?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any kind of virtual call (whether on interface or directly on a class - *all* interface calls are virtual!) will not be inlined by CLR JIT. That said, interface calls are slightly slower because they must always go through the potentially-remoted/proxied path, and because they have to shift `this`-pointer to point at the beginning of the class before entering the body of the function. Virtual calls directly on class members never have to do the shift, and, unless the class is derived from `MarshalByRefObject`, do not hit the proxying checks.

That said, performance differences between these two are very minor, so you should probably ignore them and focus on cleanliness of design and ease of implementation instead.